# How to inject the implementation of an interface that recides in another jar

Tags: java, jar, glassfish, ejb, cdi

I have an application called A packaged as a war.

I have an interface called CustomerLogic packaged in a jar.

Application A has a dependency and includes interface CustomerLogic in its war.

Now I would like to give this application to different customers so they can write their own logic by creating a class, implementing interface CustomerLogic, package it as a(EJB?) jar. And deploy that to the application server, in this case Glassfish.

So in my application code I have:

```
@Inject
private CustomerLogic customerLogic;//This will hopefully inject any implementation of the interface
```

But this fails to deploy since there are no implementations of CustomerLogic available yet.

So I create a customer specific jar that contains:

```
public class VolvoLogic implements CustomerLogic
```

and deploys this to the glassfish. 
But this fails cause the interface can't be found, it resides in application A's war.

Am I thinking about this in the wrong way. What is the best way to do this.
I don't think I want to create an EAR cause I don't want to rebuild the application every time a new customer wants it. I just want to ship the standard untouched application and they can implement their own logic.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, due to class loader isolation, two modules deployed to the glassfish will never be able to speak to each other. So what options does that leave me...

Comment: It should work using the remote interface and the global JNDI name. If you specify `@Remote` on your interface, then on deployment it should print out the global JNDI name that can be used to look the service up remotely.